# how can i find additional sample code from android sdk?

Tags: android

for example I wanna use PopMenu,
then I wanna find some sample code:as we all know that the android sdk contains all the sample code for all the android components but

how do i know under which path I should do the search ? 
because they are under different folders.

it's really disturbing me that every time taking that much time to find it.

Comment: `<your setup sdk location>\samples\<android sdk version>`. For me, it's `E:\AndrodSDK\samples`.

If you setup with default, I think your SDK location will be in `C:\Users\<your user>\Android`

Comment: If downloading from GitHub is not an issue then you can simply use Android Studio's _Import a code sample_ feature to download the repository and build it for you. It appears in the _Welcome to Android Studio_ window.

Answer (score 0):

Please start your android studio and follow below steps :

1. Start Android Studio and Open SDK Manager.

[image]

2. Now click on '**Launch Stand alone SDK Manager**' and check if samples
   are downloaded or not. If not then please download it.

[image]

3. After downloading samples please click on '**File**' menu and import
   your samples.

[image]

Edited :

Kindly note that as of Android Studio 1.4 Preview 2, 'Import Sample' moved to ' File -> New -> Import sample'.

[image]

Thank you.!!

Comment: @user3214620 : As of Android Studio 1.4 Preview 2, Import Sample button is moved to File -> New -> Import sample..!!